# Posting JSON boolean Django

Tags: json, django, post

I'm trying to send a POST request containing a boolean value like this:

```
{
"is_manager": true
}
```

The request is then handled by an overriden adapter from django-allauth:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class CustomUserAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        """
        Saves a new `User` instance using information provided in the
        signup form.
        """
        from allauth.account.utils import user_field

        user = super().save_user(request, user, form, False)
        user_field(user, 'is_manager', request.data.get('is_manager', False))
        user.save()
        return user
```

But i get this error:

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

I tried using json.loads but this method only accepts strings as argument. What can i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary hack: instead of sending `true` i can send `"True"`. This gets correctly handled.

Answer (score 0):

This one is correct to add boolean values in JSON.

```
{ "is_manager": True }
```

Comment: I don't think so